# how to prove the following equation using definition of limits

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{sinx}{x}}=1$$
or can only use some other methods like the l'Hôpital's Rule to solve it

Comment: Using l'Hopital on this limit is dangerous. The reason is that you need to know the derivative of $\sin x$, and in the process of finding the derivative of $\sin x$ by evaluating $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(x+h) - \sin x}{h}$, you will have to find the limit $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin h}{h}$. There are better ways, though.

Comment: Watch [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-derivative-rules/ab-derivtive-rules-opt-vids/v/sinx-over-x-as-x-approaches-0).

Comment: Sandwitch Theorem, of course.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/75130/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-x-to0-frac-sin-xx-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I prove that the limit is $1$ using $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition.**

*Sketch Work:*

Since
$$\cos x<\frac{\sin x}{x}<1,$$
we have 
$$\bigg|\frac{\sin x}{x}-1\bigg|<1-\cos x$$
and $1-\cos x=2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}\leqslant\frac{x^2}{2}$  hence
$$\bigg|\frac{\sin x}{x}-1\bigg|\leqslant\frac{x^2}{2}$$

**Solution:**

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. 
Choose $\delta = \sqrt{2\varepsilon}>0.$
Then for any $0<|x|<\delta = \sqrt{2\varepsilon},$ we have 
$$x^2<2\varepsilon.$$
Therefore,
$$\bigg| \frac{\sin x}{x} - 1 \bigg| \leq \frac{x^2}{2}<\varepsilon.$$
Hence, 
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1.$$